# Convert from flat one-hot encoding to list of indices with variable length

Tags: python, numpy, functional-programming

I have a list of integers, which I convert to variable one-hot encoding. For example, consider a list:

```
l = [(4, func1), (3, func2), (6, func3)]
```

The list's meaning is: The function object `func1` accepts integers in the range 0..3, `func2` can be called as `func2(0)`, `func2(1)`, or `func2(3)`, etc.

This list is turned into a list of 4 + 3 + 6 = 13 boolean values. Yes, this is not quite the classical one-hot encoding. That means that the return value:

```
one_hot = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

should result in the function call

```
func1(1)
```

Another example, if `one_hot` contains

```
one_hot = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

the resulting function call should be

```
func3(5)
```

I'm now looking for an efficient, elegant solution to turn the list of boolean values into a function call. Is there one that uses NumPy's functions in an elegant way instead of creating an explicit loop?

Comment: Concatenate an `np.arange` array for each entry in `l`, then index that array with your "one hot" vector? For this example, that would look like the array `[0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6]`.

Comment: That's a really clever idea. A cute way to do that: `np.r_[tuple(map(slice, l))][np.argmax(one_hot)]`.

Comment: But that gives me only the argument, not the function I need to call. I should have made that more explicit in the question, sorry. (Off to edit…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
func1 = lambda x: 1*x
func2 = lambda x: 2*x
func3 = lambda x: 3*x

l = [(4, func1), (3, func2), (6, func3)]

one_hot = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

r = [t[0] for t in l]
a = np.repeat(np.arange(len(l)), r)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

param = np.arange(len(one_hot)) - np.repeat(np.r_[0, np.cumsum(r)[:-1]], r)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

idx = np.where(one_hot==1)[0]
# array([ 1,  5,  9, 12])

[f(x) for f, x in zip(l[a[idx], 1], param[idx])]
# [1]
```

Output with `one_hot = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])` as input:

```
[1, 2, 6, 15]  # [func1(1), func2(1), func3(2), func3(5)]
```

Comment: I tried both versions, and I went with this one. The reason is simply a matter of taste, but I'd like to stress I would accept both if that was possible…

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
import numpy as np

def decoder(l, one_hot):
    boundaries = np.cumsum(l)
    value = np.argmax(one_hot)
    upper = np.searchsorted(boundaries, value)

    func = upper + 1
    arg = value if upper == 0 else value - boundaries[upper - 1]

    return func, arg
```

```
>>> decoder([4, 3, 6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
(3, 5)
>>> decoder([4, 3, 6], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
(1, 1)
```

Comment: I tried both versions, and I went with the proposal by @mozway. The reason is simply a matter of taste, but I'd like to stress I would accept both if that was possible…